# React native Ui design or android ui design?

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, xml

I started learning ReactJs and I realized that making complex UI is Ok in react and I can implement any design that I want but when it comes to android I can't figure out how to make those complex designs without losing performance and encountering with bugs. So is there any thing that I should learn to feel free to design in android and customize UI in whatever way I want like doing css stuff in react? or should I learn react native? I spent months to learn android and it is hard for me to change my plan to develop react native apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with ReactJs you should study only React native that allows you develop apps will works in both IOS and Android, for a perfect design you can use a live tool like [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/).

Actually the general concept of developing mobile apps by using react native and reactJS are same. You write the JSX on both platform. The only major difference is that the rendering mechanism that react uses is quite different from the other one.

React JS is actually front end library which is developed by Facebook and is used for handling view layer for web and mobile apps. It allows u to create reusbale UI components and is currently one of the most popular Javascript library and it has strong foundation and large community behind it.

Therefore, it completely depends upon the need of customers and the business what kind of mobile application they are looking for and is required for your business whether android or iOS.